# tensorflow : loop value in placeholder shape [None]

Tags: python, tensorflow

My question is as follows: if I have a placeholder with shape of `'None'`, how can I write the code in tensorflow to loop the value of shape of `'None'`? For example, given a a placeholder, if I predefined the shape, I can write:

```
[i for i in range(placeholder.shape[0].value)]
```

But how can I write the code when the shape is `'None'`? I have tried

```
[i for i in tf.range(tf.shape(placeholder)[0])]
```

It does not work at all. I also tried to use `tf.while_loop`, but still can not get expected result. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much

Comment: In a graph, if placeholder's shape is known, for example, ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3, 2]), then in the graph, I can write a function that return a list [i for i in range(ph.shape[0].value)]. However, if ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2]), since the shape is None, if I want to use range(ph.shape[0].value), it will not work. So I use tf.shape() to get the dynamic shape and then use range(tf.shape(ph)[0]). But it still does not work. I just wonder how we can write in tensorflow to get range of a dynamic shape. Hope it is clear this time. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may read [how to as a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question. You can [edit] your question instead of adding clarification in comments. Consider adding error message along with examples that don't work. Remember that readability of your post is important. You could also add your attempt with while loop

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding a comment with details. All details should be in the question itself

Comment: In addition, don't use tags such as python or tensorflow in your title

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use tf.scan:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.InteractiveSession()
placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)  # The shape of the placeholder is unknown for now
def fn(_, x):
  y = 2 * x  # Do something with this value
  return y
shape = tf.scan(fn, tf.shape(placeholder))
feed_dict = {placeholder: np.zeros((2, 3, 4))}
print(shape.eval(feed_dict))
```